# MongoDb ensureIndex on ObjectIds

Tags: mongodb

Is it worth while to do ensureIndex on a field that will always have a value of an ObjectId?

Basically we have a user collection and "stuff" collection.  A thing (single row) in stuff will always be related to a user in collection.  So we store the ObjectId for that user in a field in that thing.

```
{
   'thingTitle': 'Title',
   'owner': ObjectId(fromUserCollection)
}
```

A user will always have multiple objects for the most part.  Is it worth while to put an ensureIndex on that?  Also how does ensureIndex behave with ObjectIds?

Comment: Depends on the queries but guessing by the type of field I would say yes. The index will just store the 12 byte storage representation of the ObjectId like it does with the unique _id index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are querying on that field eg. `db.thing_collection.find({user: userObjectId})` you will need an index on that field.

Comment: Yes we are, its one of our search options so it will be hit quite often.  My I guess misunderstanding (for lack of a better word), was could ensureIndex be useful with ObjectId's.  But from these comments it seems as though it is.

Comment: ``ObjectId`` s are not special data types in terms of their need for indexing, if that is what you mean. As any other data type, they need to be indexed if you want to skip long table scans and get right to your desired dataset.

Answer (score 0):

yes, ensuring index on the thing collection will have good impact in terms of lookup performance on your application :)